# referencing class object from another class method

Tags: python, function, class, methods, tkinter

So, I have this GUI that creates a large empty frame with a Button, clicking the button will call a function(method?) that generates a smaller frame within(of a different class), with entry fields, as well as create a duplicate Button underneath the smaller frame to repeat the process over and over, filling the GUI with the smaller frames. Each small frame is equipped with a 'DELETE' button that destroys the small frame itself...my problem is I also want this to destroy the Button underneath it, which was generated by a method in a different class(the class of the large frame). I can't seem to get the 'delete_aircraft' function to destroy the Button... I've commented out that line of the delete_aircraft function because I know refering to 'self' is incorrect in this case. How can I get rid of each instance of the 'newaircraft' Button when it is created by a method in a different class?

Basically I want to reverse the operation of the 'addnew' function.

Here's the code:

```
class Fleet_Creation(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, width=1000, height=700, bg='grey80', relief='ridge', bd=3)
        fleet_title=tk.Label(text='Fleet Creation Module', font='arial 20 bold', bg='grey80', justify='center')
        fleet_title.place(anchor='nw', x=350, y=5)
        self.newaircraft = tk.Button(text='Add New Aircraft...', font='arial 15', relief='raised', bd=3, bg='SteelBlue1', command=self.addnew)
        self.newaircraft.place(anchor='nw', x=78, y=45)

    def addnew(self):
        xcoord = self.newaircraft.winfo_x()
        ycoord = self.newaircraft.winfo_y()
        self.newaircraft.destroy()
        addnewframe = New_Aircraft(Fleet_Creation)
        if ycoord<600:
            addnewframe.place(anchor='nw', x=(xcoord-80), y=ycoord)
            self.newaircraft = tk.Button(text='Add New Aircraft...', font='arial 15', relief='raised', bd=3, bg='SteelBlue1', command=self.addnew)
            self.newaircraft.place(anchor='nw', x=(xcoord), y=(ycoord+100))
        elif ycoord>=600:
            addnewframe.place(anchor='nw', x=(xcoord+253), y=(ycoord-ycoord+47))
            self.newaircraft = tk.Button(text='Add New Aircraft...', font='arial 15', relief='raised', bd=3, bg='SteelBlue1', command=self.addnew)
            self.newaircraft.place(anchor='nw', x=(xcoord+333), y=(ycoord-ycoord+148))
        elif xcoord > 800:
            self.newaircraft.destroy()


class New_Aircraft(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, width=333, height=100, bg='grey60', relief='ridge', bd=5 )
        n_number=tk.Label(self, text='N-Number:', font='arial 10 bold', bg='grey60')
        n_number.place(anchor='nw', x=3, y=3)
        n_number_entry=tk.Entry(self, font='arial 10 bold', relief='sunken', bd=2, width=7)
        n_number_entry.place(anchor='nw', x=75, y=3)
        type=tk.Label(self, text='Aircraft Type(ICAO):', font='arial 10 bold', bg='grey60')
        type.place(anchor='nw', x=135, y=3)
        type_entry=tk.Entry(self, font='arial 10 bold', width=7, relief='sunken', bd=2)
        type_entry.place(anchor='nw', x=265, y=3)
        aircraft_category = ['CATEGORY...','AIRPLANE','ROTORCRAFT']
        aircraft_class = ['CLASS...','ASEL', 'ASES', 'AMEL', 'AMES']
        aircraft_type = ['TYPE...','JET', 'TURBINE', 'RECIPROCATING', 'GLIDER']
        accat = tk.StringVar()
        accls = tk.StringVar()
        actype = tk.StringVar()
        Category = tk.OptionMenu(self, accat, 'AIRPLANE', 'ROTORCRAFT')
        Class = tk.OptionMenu(self, accls, 'ASEL', 'ASES', 'AMEL', 'AMES')
        Type = tk.OptionMenu(self, actype, 'JET', 'TURBINE', 'RECIPROCATING', 'GLIDER')
        Category.place(anchor='nw', x=2, y=40)
        Class.place(anchor='nw', x=117, y=40)
        Type.place(anchor='nw', x=205, y=40)
        Category.config(bg='grey60', font='arial 8 bold', bd=0)
        Class.config(bg='grey60', font='arial 8 bold', bd=0)
        Type.config(bg='grey60', font='arial 8 bold', bd=0)
        accat.set('CATEGORY...')
        accls.set('CLASS...')
        actype.set('TYPE...')
        h1 = tk.Label(self, font='arial 1', bg='grey60', relief='sunken', width=315)
        h1.place(anchor='nw', x=0, y=28)
        self.addbutton=tk.Button(self, text='ADD', height=2, font='arial 10', bg='DodgerBlue2', command=self.add)
        self.addbutton.place(anchor='nw', x=283, y=40)
        self.delete = tk.Button(self, text='DELETE', font='arial 7 bold', bg='red', width=30, justify='center', command=self.delete_aircraft)
        self.delete.place(anchor='nw',x=45,y=69)


    #create function to render addbutton disabled
    def add(self):
        self.addbutton.config(state='disabled')
        #other stuff

    def delete_aircraft(self):
        self.destroy()
        #destroy 'newaircraft' button created by the addnew function
        #self.newaircraft.destroy()
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you use the `place` algorithm to organize your widgets, you don't really care where the widget reference is stored. Instead of storing the Button as `self.newaircraft` (i.e. store as attribute of the instance of `FleetCreation`), you  may store it as `addnewframe.newaircraft` (i.e. store as attribute of the instance of `New_Aircraft`). So, you can uncomment you last line safely, as `newaircraft` is now an attribute of `self`. However, I would invert the two lines: first destroy `self.newaircraft` then destroy `self`.